# How do I stop my Moto G from pestering me about Motorola ID related things?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, 5.1-lollipop, alerts

I have a Moto G 4G (2nd gen?) running Android 5.1 Lollipop. I would like to disable or suppress the endless alerts I get from it about *"Sign in problem"*'s and *"Motorola  ID unlinked"* related to Motorola services, none of which I wish to use.

I thought unlinking my "Motorola ID" might do this but it just complains even more i.e. the *"Motorola  ID unlinked"* alert.

How do I do this?

Comment: Not sure, but someone back to 4.4  was done this: settings->security & screen lock->Device administrators and turned off "Motorola Device Policy". Next, settings->Motorola Device ID, tap the three dot menu control on the top right, and choose "unlink account".

Comment: @user3344236 - ok, have done that...how long until it starts repeatedly  complaining about the "Motorola Device Policy" being turned off, which it instantly did. :)

Comment: Can you anyway login in you google account while you receive this annoying prompt?

Comment: Just thinking aloud: if you can figure which app is throwing those alerts, you might simply "freeze" that (see: [disable-app tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/disable-app/info), [bloatware tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bloatware/info)). Which might require root, or might not – some system apps can be disabled without root, others can't.

Comment: @Izzy - I'll see how I get on with the Motorola Device Policy turned off over the next couple of days.

Comment: Uncheck the *allow notifications* checkbox in the Application Settings?

Comment: @user3344236 - your top comment seems to have done the trick. Make it an answer and I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems we have to apply as back to 4.4 and do this: settings->security & screen lock->Device administrators and turn off "Motorola Device Policy". Next, settings->Motorola Device ID, tap the three dot menu control on the top right, and choose "unlink account". Restart (reboot) as a supplementary measure.

Answer (score 1):

Long click the notification and you should be able to see what app is causing it; disable "device notification" from there or app settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Android 7 on a Moto G5, and a Moto 360 watch.

To disconnect the Motorola ID:

1. Open the Moto Connect app
2. Click "Change account"
3. Click the 3 vertical dots (top, right corner)
4. Click "Sign out".
5. You will be prompted with a checkbox to agree to the privacy policy. Uncheck this checkbox. You will get a message saying all data will be deleted. Accept.
6. Uninstall the app.